# Is there any way to calculate the gravitational potential energy of an object without knowing it's mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

I'm trying to solve for the mass of an object in a gravitational field, but with the equation $PE= \frac{GMm}{r}$ I need to know the object's change in gravitational potential energy, which I need the object's mass to calculate I think. The only other way I know of calculating this type of work done is $\mathrm{Force \ x \  distance}$ (which I guess comes out to the $PE= \frac{GMm}{r}$ equation again. So is there any way to find the potential energy of an object in a gravitational field without knowing its mass? Surely it's been done before, it just seems like a dead end.

Edit: For clarification I mean I'm trying to find the mass $m$ of a small object in the field of a significantly larger mass $M$.

Comment: What if you knew the acceleration and mass of another object interacting with your object at a certain distance?

Comment: I know the mass of the field producing significantly larger mass M, and because that mass is so significantly larger, its acceleration would basically be zero. However, I can calculate the acceleration of the smaller mass m through the equation for field strength g at distance r with the equation g=GM/r^2

Comment: Exactly what is the question you're trying to answer? That is, is there more information given? Also it's best if you use MathJaX to formulate your equations so they can be more easily read.

Comment: Nevermind, I already found an answer. But thanks for your responses people.